# Is there a way to do what ListViewHeaderItem exactly do?

Tags: c#, uwp, itemscontrol, collectionviewsource, groupstyle

I want to realize a custom view just like `ListView`.

Now the problem is I want get a Tapped event from group header, maybe more.
It always creates [GroupItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.GroupItem?view=winrt-19041) as group view, and can't be change.

I found what ListView do is create [ListViewHeaderItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewheaderitem?view=winrt-19041) by the system and added to the visual tree when realizing the `GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate`.
**My question is any way to do this?**

cs:

```cs
public class CustomView : ItemsControl
```

xaml:

```xml
<CollectionViewSource x:Name="itemCVS" IsSourceGrouped="True" 
               Source="{x:Bind Groups}" ItemsPath="Items"/>
...
<CustomView ItemsSource="{x:Bind itemCVS.View}">
  <CustomView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    <GroupStyle.Panel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <CustomPanel/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GroupStyle.Panel>
  </CustomView.GroupStyle>
</CustomView>
```

CustomView Visual Tree:

```
CustomView
 Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Border
  Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ScrollViewer
   Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Border
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid
     Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter
      Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsPresenter
       Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentControl
       CustomPanel
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.GroupItem
         Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid
          Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentControl
           Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentPresenter
            Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock
          Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsControl
           Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsPresenter
            Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentControl
            CustomPanel
             Item 1
             Item 2
```

ListView Visual Tree:

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView
 Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Border
  Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ScrollViewer
   Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Border
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid
     Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter
      Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsPresenter
       Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentControl
       Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsStackPanel
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewHeaderItem
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewHeaderItem
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewItem 1
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewItem 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You code has generated the HeaderItem.

Because your CustomerView inherits from [ItemsControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol?view=winrt-19041), the generated HeaderItem has no style.

So if you want to do this, please manually add  to change the style like following.

```
<CustomerView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListViewHeaderItem>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewHeaderItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupStyle>
 </CustomerView.GroupStyle>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I will try it.